# SQL Server 2008 Debugger Attach?

Tags: sql-server-2008, debugging

I have seen a few posts here about using the native MSSQL 2008 functionality to debug and step through TSQL.

In a Visual Studio 2010 .NET C# console app, I use simple ADO.NET to send some params to a stored proc. I can run it in the debugger and see what happens in the .NET code up until the point where the SqlCommand is executed. How can I get the debugger (or any debugger) to fire on the MSSQL side so I can follow data from the C# all the way to/though the DB?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capture what is sent cross the wire, use [SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173918%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

[Using SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx)

If you are having problems stepping into a stored procedure from Visual Studio:

- [How to: Enable Transact-SQL Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s0fk6z6e.aspx)
- [Walkthrough: Debug a Transact-SQL Stored Procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yet1b7by.aspx)

[Please note: your mileage may vary; I've known systems where this just wouldn't work. So much so, I never try to step into TSQL any more...]

Comment: The Profiler doesn't let me step into the sproc and see what it's doing. If I only use Profiler, than I have to jam a lot of print/debug/select statements into the sproc.